# Istio spec/hosts don't work in non-default namespace

Tags: istio

I have the following for `stg` namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: stg
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: stg
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
  namespace: stg
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - '*'
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-1
  namespace: stg
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx
        port:
          number: 80
```

I need `spec/hosts` to be `app1.my.domain` instead of `*`

It works fine in `default` namespace but not in `stg` namespace

`stg` namespace has `istio-injection=enabled`

Any ideas why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please clarify what's the output from `curl -v` and `curl -v -H "host: app1.my.domain"` when you change the virtual service hosts from `*` to `app1.my.domain`? I assume when you're doing that all of your dependencies (deployment,gateway,virtual service) are deployed in the stg namespace, correct?

Comment: Perhaps the VirtualService cannot route traffic from the ingressgateway (which exists in the namespace istio-system) to a service called nginx. Try changing the VirtualService destination to `nginx.stg.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: @Jakub here's that output:
`*   Trying 54.217.59.118...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to stg.demo.kagarlickij.com (54.217.59.118) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: stg.demo.kagarlickij.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< date: Thu, 15 Apr 2021 16:50:27 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host stg.demo.kagarlickij.com left intact
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: @LudovicC I tried but it didn't help. when it's `hosts: "*"` AWS ALB DNS works with both `host: nginx.stg.svc.cluster.local` and `host: nginx`. When it's `hosts: "stg.demo.kagarlickij.com"` neither of them work

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a typo in your configuration. You gateway.spec.servers[0].hosts[0] should be equal to `stg.demo.kagarlickij.com`. Your VirtualService.spec.http[0].route[0].destination.host should be `nginx.stg.svc.cluster.local` and VirtualService.spec.hosts should be equal to `[stg.demo.kagarlickij.com]`